# Correlation matrix for panel data in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, panel, correlation

I want to create a correlation matrix for a data panel. The dataframe contains data on 15 numerical variables on a monthly basis for 11 years.

I would like to know, if possible, how to generate a single correlation matrix for the variables of this type of dataframe.

The alternative I have in mind would be to generate one correlation matrix per year, but I would like to know if it is possible to make only one correlation matrix for the whole dataframe in case the number of years is very large (which would make it unfeasible to make one matrix for each year).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the dataframe you're working with? It will make it much easier for others to answer and provide an example of what you would like to do.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. Please read the following documentation, then [edit] and rephrase the question. [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), & [On Topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Always provide a [mre] with **code, data, errors, current output, and expected output, as text** & you're expected to [try to solve the problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592).

Comment: I'm sorry I couldn't offer code but the only thing I could have offered was a sample dataframe (I should have but I'm new to StackOverFlow as a user and didn't know how to do it so I described it as accurately as possible in text). 
I have tried to look for solutions on my own both outside SO and in SO but I have only found cases for R which have not clarified anything for me in Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you're mainly looking for the `corr` method of a DataFrame. Consider this example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(30, 5)).add_prefix("feature_")
df["year"] = np.repeat(["2012", "2013", "2014"], 10)

print(df.head()) # first 5 rows. Note that there are 30 rows
   feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4  year
0   0.548814   0.715189   0.602763   0.544883   0.423655  2012
1   0.645894   0.437587   0.891773   0.963663   0.383442  2012
2   0.791725   0.528895   0.568045   0.925597   0.071036  2012
3   0.087129   0.020218   0.832620   0.778157   0.870012  2012
4   0.978618   0.799159   0.461479   0.780529   0.118274  2012
```

Subset the numerical columns you want to be in the cormat (in this case I use `.filter` to get just the "feature_X" columns) and use  `DataFrame.corr`:

```
cormat = df.filter(like="feature").corr()

print(cormat)
           feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4
feature_0   1.000000   0.004582   0.412658   0.269969   0.151162
feature_1   0.004582   1.000000  -0.200808   0.140620  -0.138652
feature_2   0.412658  -0.200808   1.000000  -0.019439   0.284211
feature_3   0.269969   0.140620  -0.019439   1.000000  -0.063653
feature_4   0.151162  -0.138652   0.284211  -0.063653   1.000000
```

If you want to get a correlation matrix at a grouping of some other variable, you can use `.groupby` first.

```
annual_cormat = df.groupby("year").corr()

print(annual_cormat)
                feature_0  feature_1  feature_2  feature_3  feature_4
year                                                                 
2012 feature_0   1.000000   0.359721  -0.266740   0.285998  -0.526528
     feature_1   0.359721   1.000000  -0.330484   0.180620  -0.580236
     feature_2  -0.266740  -0.330484   1.000000   0.262000   0.428895
     feature_3   0.285998   0.180620   0.262000   1.000000  -0.144745
     feature_4  -0.526528  -0.580236   0.428895  -0.144745   1.000000
2013 feature_0   1.000000   0.135499   0.704653   0.081326   0.453111
     feature_1   0.135499   1.000000  -0.385677   0.732700  -0.065941
     feature_2   0.704653  -0.385677   1.000000  -0.607016   0.143572
     feature_3   0.081326   0.732700  -0.607016   1.000000   0.107971
     feature_4   0.453111  -0.065941   0.143572   0.107971   1.000000
2014 feature_0   1.000000  -0.624004   0.056185   0.351376  -0.038286
     feature_1  -0.624004   1.000000   0.103911  -0.284685   0.266124
     feature_2   0.056185   0.103911   1.000000   0.249860   0.145773
     feature_3   0.351376  -0.284685   0.249860   1.000000  -0.347361
     feature_4  -0.038286   0.266124   0.145773  -0.347361   1.000000
```

Comment: Thank you for trying to offer a solution to my question. The dataframe you have generated is practically identical to the one I work with, except for the date column which is at a monthly level (Jan-2012, Feb-2012...) and not at an annual basis but for this case it works the same.

Unfortunately, this solution is the alternative to which I referred to avoid and is that by making a .groupby() with .corr() you are generating a correlation matrix **for each year** while I would like to generate only **one** correlation matrix for the entire dataframe for all variables and all years at once.

Comment: Did my approach without the `groupby` not provide the result you wanted? `cormat = df.filter(like="feature").corr()` It's right before the part where I use the `groupby`